# Looking for Android, offline, mobile app for field campaign?

Tags: vector, android, mobile, software-recommendations, offline

In the frame of an international project in agriculture monitoring, I have to propose a mobile app that will be used as a reference for field working. The **minimum** requirements of such an application are:

- visualize the **real time** geo-location on a **background map or satellite image** (manually uploaded)
- possibility to **pinpoint** and **label** the crop type (i.e. add a vector layer with attribute via forms)
- possibility to work **offline** (i.e. loading the background image in memory)
- **multi-platform** (phone/tablet, Android(priority)/iOS...)
- **free**

Several apps have already been identified (Geowiki pictures, GIS cloud, Poimapper, Wolf-GIS, GeoODK collect, Opendatakit, Geopaparazzi, GeoNode, ESRI ArcGIS) but none of them (at least at this point of the analysis) completly fulfilled the requirements. Do you have other suggestions ?

Comment: QGis runs on android devices too, see for example http://www.upande.com/about-us/blog/140-naivasha-data-on-qgis-on-android

Comment: @DJack It's a nice list you have there. What are your feelings on what you've installed and tried?

Comment: the GeoNode / Arbiter combo is interesting. Maybe look at https://github.com/ROGUE-JCTD/Arbiter-Android

Answer (score 0):

GeoODK, is a good solution. It is currently being used for agg monitoring by geoglam. Its nice because you can take your maps offline with you as well as other layers. Also you can collect polygon as well as points and other spatial features. A new release was just launched.  Check it out. geoodk.com